# How to make my div with role="button" attribute clickable with the enter key

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, event-delegation

I have an app that needs to be fully navigable by keyboard.  When I click on the header of a div (generated by a javascript/jquery function), an event listener is triggered. I was able to highlight the headers with `tab` by adding the attributes `role="button"` and `tabindex="0"`, but it's still only clickable by mouse. The ARIA documentation is kind of hard to follow and I don't have much time left.

HTML

```
<section id="js-item-root">

  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="item-header js-item-header" id="1" role="button" tabindex="1">Title of the First Div</div>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="item-header js-item-header" id="2" role="button" tabindex="2" >Title of the Second Div</div>
    <p>This is also a paragraph</p>
  </div>

</section>
```

CSS

```
.item {
  border: solid black 2px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.item-header {
  border-bottom: solid black 1px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

Javascript/Jquery:

```
function handleHeaderClick() {
  $('#js-item-root').on('click', '.js-item-header', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(this.id)
  }
}
```

how to I get the console.log to work when I highlight the header with the `tab` key and press `enter`?

```
//Progress update detailed below
```

I was able to get my code working right by trading my `<div>`s for `<button>`s and  setting the width to `width: 100%`, but I still want to learn a way to make a div ACT like a button. I tried creating a new function that sawpped the `'click'` for a `'keypress'`, but that didn't work. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Hint: You need a key event listener also on those elements and check which key was used

Comment: I've tried "$('#js-item-root').on('keypress', '.js-item-header', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(this.id)
  }" , but it's still not working with the attribute.

Comment: Ok, that should work. But your question was about keys so you need a key event listener also ... like `.on('keydown'...`

Comment: neither 'keypress' or 'keydown' are working

Comment: Create a runnable demo that shows what you tried and be a bit more specific than "not working". Any errors, what actually happens etc?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes using a button element isn't possible without creating invalid html - e.g. when you need to use block level elements such as headings and divs inside the button. For those times I use the following snippet to get back what you lose from using a real `button`:

```
// --------------------------------------------
// Allow role=button to behave like a real <button> el.
// by triggering the click on spacebar/enter keydown
// --------------------------------------------

document.querySelectorAll('div[role="button"]').forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
        const keyDown = e.key !== undefined ? e.key : e.keyCode;
        if ( (keyDown === 'Enter' || keyDown === 13) || (['Spacebar', ' '].indexOf(keyDown) >= 0 || keyDown === 32)) {
            // (prevent default so the page doesn't scroll when pressing space)
            e.preventDefault();
            el.click();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Better to attach a listener to the whole document and use event delegation, rather than attaching to every element. This won't cover dynamically created elements.

Comment: I disagree that it's automatically "better" to use event delegation. I'd say you should keep things as simple as possible and use event delegation only when the need arises.